# Dealing with a column with multiple data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have below script to read .txt file and insert them to Database table.
But the problem with the data types in "nid" column. It contains string, float, and nan value.
I just want to convert the datatype to "str" of that column in that dataframe and replace nan with None to insert null value.

If i do like this:

```
nid = row[18].astype(str).replace(np.nan, None),
```

then getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

All codes as follows.

```
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'test.txt')

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:mypass@192.168.11.72:3306/xyz")

meta = MetaData(engine)
notsubmitted = Table('notsubmitted', meta,
   Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
   Column('name', String(250)),
   Column('cno', String(250)),
   Column('createdate', String(250)),
   Column('fname', String(250)),
   Column('mname', String(250)),
   Column('sex', String(250)),
   Column('address', String(250)),
   Column('tin', String(250)),
   Column('nid', String(100)))

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='~', dtype=str, encoding = 'cp1252')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    stmt = notsubmitted.insert().values( 
        name = row[1].strip(),
        cno = row[2].strip(),
        createdate = row[3].strip(),
        fname = row[4].strip(),
        mname = row[5].strip(),
        sex = row[6].strip(),
        address= row[7].strip(),
        tin= row[12],
        nid = row[18]
        )
    conn = engine.connect()
    res = conn.execute(stmt)
```

Thanks.

Comment: A pandas column with strings will be `object` dtype.  It there are numbers they will be int or float (e.g. `np.nan`).  `astype` does not apply in such a column.

Comment: So how can i insert the nan value as None.

Comment: If you read the error - `'str' object has no attribute 'astype'` - this isn't saying `"pandas string column" has no attribute 'astype'`. The issue is that `row[18]` is a single value only, and it's just a string. did you mean to replace values in the whole column, e.g. with `df.iloc[:, 18].astype(str).replace(np.nan, None)`? Also if you convert to string first, you won't have any `np.nan`s left. Maybe replace NaNs and then coerce to String?

Comment: also I don't think this has anything to do with numpy or dask - is that right? if so, can you remove those tags?